# IDE says: "Warning: Name 'X' can be undefined"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, undefined

I have found similar questions on here but I haven't been able to find the solution to my problem.

I am new to python and I am revising an old project that I created after learning more efficient ways to write code. The program runs without error, however I would like to resolve the warnings I'm getting. Thank you!

```
while True:
try:
    user_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, your name can't be a number.\n"
          "Please try again.")
    continue
else:
    user_name = str(user_name)
    break

print("Hello, " + user_name.capitalize() + "! " + user_age + " is the perfect age to learn about "
                                                         "the planets in our solar system!")
```

[Picture: Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOSkR.png)

[Picture: Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REhAt.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and the warnings are wrong.

It's complaining because if something were to crash inside the "input" function, and the exception is caught, then the `user_name` or `user_age` variables will be unassigned going forward. However because you call "continue" in both except statements this bad situation cannot occur, but the warning checker isn't smart enough to identify this.

There are different but equally correct ways to write your code so that PyCharm won't complain.

```
while True:
    user_age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    if user_age.isdigit() and int(user_age) > 0:
        return int(user_age)
    else:
        print("Please enter a positive whole number...")
```